# How do I echo saved data outside the function?

Tags: variables

I know the data I want is stored as *$lineOne* and I can *echo* that inside the function. But I want to get the data outside of the function.

I've tired:

```
$lineOne; 
$instance['lineOne'];
```

Here's the code where I want to insert `$lineOne` (line 11) and the widget where the variable is loaded/saved: http://pastie.org/7142717

Comment: You do that already. What is your question?

Comment: toscho -> I do what? If I move the PHP echo code outside the function, it returns nothing

Comment: This is a PHP question not a WordPress one. @MadsRH, you should [look into scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: This is not a WP question...

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to declare $lineOne as global inside your function:

```
global $lineOne;
```

Messy way of coding though.

Comment: Thanks, I've tired to add global $lineOne; just at the start of the function, but I still cannot echo it outside. Any suggestion regarding the coding style is recived with applause.

Comment: This is really general PHP stuff rather than WordPress...

Comment: but isn't there something that I can write to get the string from the database? like get_option